# What's the difference between 'Array<_>' & 'Array'

Tags: xcode, swift2

I'm getting this error when trying to build the app:

> `<unknown>:0: error: cannot assign value of type 'Array<_>' to type 'Array'`

but Xcode is not indicating a specific line or class for the failure.

If I could understand the difference between

```
Array<_>
```

&

```
Array
```

it may help me locate the issue.

Comment: [Type]() == Array<Type>(). Check the type of the Array<_thisone_> and the type of Array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't like answering my own questions but for the sake of closure

I had this line of code

```
var userTweetsArray : Array = [String]()
```

I never actually used it. Once I removed that line the error had gone.

The error was caused by assigning an array of a type in this case String to an Array of no type.

So difference is Array<_> is an array of a type and Array is not.

Comment: The correct syntax could be:
`var userTweetsArray = [String]()` (Inferred type is the best practice) or even `var userTweetsArray : [String] = [String]()`
or if you really want to keep Array keyword
`var userTweetsArray : Array<String> = [String]()`. Remember, Swift is strongly typed. If you just write `Array`, Swift answers `Array of what?`

Answer (score 0):

When you app is crashing, than you can turn on All Exceptions for Debug breakpoint. This should stop on the line where the crash appears.

You find this in Xcode on the Left Panel-> BreakPoint Navigator.
Than press the + in the bottome left corner and Add Exception Breakpoint.

It looks like that you overwrite an array with an array that has a specific value definition. Good Luck :)

Comment: It won't even compile so it doesn't get the chance to crash.

Comment: The error should appear to a line of code, can you provide it? +- 10 Lines of code and param declarations?

Comment: I got it working by removing a line of code that I was not even using anyway.  var userTweetsArray : Array = [String](). What was wrong with that code?

Comment: u should define it with the right value ... userTweetsArray : [String] = [String]() . or remove the : [String] because setting the value defines already the object and type :)

Answer (score 0):

A generic argument clause is enclosed in angle brackets ( < > )

< generic argument list >

You can replace a type parameter with a type argument that is itself a specialized version of a generic type.For example, you can replace the type parameter T in Array < T > with a specialized version of an array, Array< Int > , Array< String >, to form an array whose elements are themselves array of integers / Strings

Answer (score 0):

Regarding xour code Snippet the fix is:

> u should define it with the right value ... userTweetsArray : [String] = String . or remove the : [String] because setting the value defines already the object and type :)

Comment: How does userTweetsArray :  [String] = String ?? I get that I don't need to define the type as the value already does, but that shouldn't cause a compile error though if I do should it?

Comment: Thats one cool thing from swift. It will automaticly try to know the type of possible. String() for example returns a new instance of type string, so swift already knows the instance. Like an Array with String items in it :)

Comment: I get that but you are saying that var foo : [String] = String. Im asking how can foo which is defined as an array of Strings = String ?

Comment: ahh true, iam sorry.... i mean var foo : [String] = [String]() .... here you could remove the : [String] ... to solve your issue with the : Array -> just remove : Array and it will know that the array "userTweetsArray" is a type of [String]()

Comment: Yes ok, but leaving it there should not have prevented the code from compiling. Its the actual cause of the bug I'm interested in working out.

Comment: actualy it is preventing the compiling. An [String] is not the same as Array... you tried to put in an stack of strings into an Array .... i never heard the declaration of Array ... only NSArray .... or do i miss something?